# How can I get the size of a folder on SD card in Android?

Tags: android, size, directory, sd-card

Is it possible to easily get the size of a folder on the SD card? I use a folder for caching of images, and would like to present the total size of all cached images. Is there a way to this other than iterating over each file? They all reside inside the same folder?

Answer (score 45):

Just go through all files and sum the length of them:

```
/**
 * Return the size of a directory in bytes
 */
private static long dirSize(File dir) {

    if (dir.exists()) {
        long result = 0;
        File[] fileList = dir.listFiles();
        if (fileList != null) {
            for(int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
                // Recursive call if it's a directory
                if(fileList[i].isDirectory()) {
                    result += dirSize(fileList[i]);
                } else {
                    // Sum the file size in bytes
                    result += fileList[i].length();
                }
            }
        }
        return result; // return the file size
    }
    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: Function written by hand so it could not compile!

Comment: You might want to replace findFile by dirSize :)

Comment: i suggest to replace `dir.exists()` with `dir.isDirectory()`. if a file is given as argument NullPointerException is thrown due to listFiles() result.

Comment: @Moss The "for-each" loop is better, like Google suggest in http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#Loops

Comment: Check fileList ot being null before the loop on it

Answer (score 20):

Here's some code that avoids recursion:

```
public static long getFileSize(final File file) {
    if (file == null || !file.exists())
        return 0;
    if (!file.isDirectory())
        return file.length();
    final List<File> dirs = new LinkedList<>();
    dirs.add(file);
    long result = 0;
    while (!dirs.isEmpty()) {
        final File dir = dirs.remove(0);
        if (!dir.exists())
            continue;
        final File[] listFiles = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFiles == null || listFiles.length == 0)
            continue;
        for (final File child : listFiles) {
            // Note: if you want to get physical size and not just logical size, include directories too to the result, and not just normal files
            if (child.isDirectory()) {
                dirs.add(child);
            } else {
                result += child.length();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: this is absolutely right answer for calculating size of FILE/FOLDER

Comment: I was actually surprised to see that (on Android) each folder takes about 4KB even when it's empty. wonder why they did it this way.

Comment: @androiddeveloper It's the sector size. You'll notice that the same is true on any desktop OS.

Comment: @AndroidDev OK. Thanks

Comment: The value matches the details reported by Samsung My Files app on selected files in a folder

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes, the total size of every file in a folder (not including the folder, of course)

Comment: @ecle I see. I wonder: Does the built-in "My files" app of Samsung show anything about "Android" folder on Android 11 (which sadly restricts access to this folder for third party apps) ? Can it show the total size there? Can it show its content?

Comment: @androiddeveloper sorry, I don't have access to any Samsung device > Android 7.0+ to verify

Comment: @ecle I see. Thanks.

Comment: This adds `length()` of directories to the sum as well. Is this right? According to docs, “The return value [of `length()`] is unspecified if this pathname denotes a directory.”

Comment: @squirrel If you don't want it, have the check that it's a file, and only then accumulate

Comment: @androiddeveloper I don't think this is a question of what I want. Since the `length()` on a directory returns an unspecified value, I think it's an error to use it for directories at all?

Comment: @squirrel So don't use it.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I guess what I am suggesting is to edit the answer. I take it from the text that this answer is in a way more correct since it “calculates the physical size instead of the logical size”, which is what `length()` seems to be responsible for as it's about the only difference to other answers that can affect the result. While in fact the result is undefined.

Comment: @squirrel I've read somewhere that this is giving it as such result. If you don't trust it, change this code to how you see fit.

Answer (score 7):

you should use this code:

```
public static long getFolderSize(File f) {
    long size = 0;
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        for (File file : f.listFiles()) {    
            size += getFolderSize(file);
        }
    } else {
        size=f.length();
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Great solution for me, I am having a folder with some audio files and it works perfekt for me! (I am having no subfolders in this folder!)

Answer (score 6):

```
/**
 * Try this one for better performance
 * Mehran
 * Return the size of a directory in bytes
 **/

private static long dirSize(File dir) {
    long result = 0;

    Stack<File> dirlist= new Stack<File>();
    dirlist.clear();

    dirlist.push(dir);

    while(!dirlist.isEmpty())
    {
        File dirCurrent = dirlist.pop();

        File[] fileList = dirCurrent.listFiles();
        for(File f: fileList){
            if(f.isDirectory())
                dirlist.push(f);
            else
                result += f.length();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Since we're talking about file operations, the recursion is unlikely to account for much of the performance hit. Also, the java.util.Stack implementation is very slow. I tried to optimize a recursive algorithm with it and it was actually slower then to let the JVM do its job.

Comment: java.util.Stack class methods are synchronized. If you really want to avoid recursion it's better to use LinkedList.

Answer (score 4):

The way of #Moss is right. This is my code for those who want to change bytes to human readable format. You just need to assign path of your folder to `dirSize(String path)` and get human readable format based on byte, kilo, mega and etc.

```
private static String dirSize(String path) {

        File dir = new File(path);

        if(dir.exists()) {
            long bytes = getFolderSize(dir);
            if (bytes < 1024) return bytes + " B";
            int exp = (int) (Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024));
            String pre = ("KMGTPE").charAt(exp-1) + "";

            return String.format("%.1f %sB", bytes / Math.pow(1024, exp), pre);
        }

        return "0";
    }

    public static long getFolderSize(File dir) {
        if (dir.exists()) {
            long result = 0;
            File[] fileList = dir.listFiles();
            for(int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
                // Recursive call if it's a directory
                if(fileList[i].isDirectory()) {
                    result += getFolderSize(fileList[i]);
                } else {
                    // Sum the file size in bytes
                    result += fileList[i].length();
                }
            }
            return result; // return the file size
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: well it's another question about readability, so quite offtopic answer

Answer (score 4):

Problem with other solution is that they provide you only logical size of all files in specified directory. It will be different from actual (physical) used space. If your directory has a lot of subdirectories and/or small files, there may be a huge difference between logical and actual size of directory.

Here is what I found how to take in count physical structure of FS.

```
public static long getDirectorySize(File directory, long blockSize) {
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {

        // space used by directory itself 
        long size = file.length();

        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                // space used by subdirectory
                size += getDirectorySize(file, blockSize);
            } else {
                // file size need to rounded up to full block sizes
                // (not a perfect function, it adds additional block to 0 sized files
                // and file who perfectly fill their blocks) 
                size += (file.length() / blockSize + 1) * blockSize;
            }
        }
        return size;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You can use [`StatFs`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html) to get block size:

```
public static long getDirectorySize(File directory) {
    StatFs statFs = new StatFs(directory.getAbsolutePath());
    long blockSize;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        blockSize = statFs.getBlockSizeLong()
    } else {
        blockSize = statFs.getBlockSize();
    }

    return getDirectorySize(directory, blockSize);
}
```

Comment: I've noticed that if I call "length()" on a directory, I don't get 0, but a real number. Is it possible that instead of using what you've done you can just use "length()" on the directories (and of course do the rest- adding the size of normal files) ?

Comment: Did you mean for `return getDirectorySize(directory, blockSize);` to just be `return blockSize`?

Comment: Thank you so much for providing this answer. This was our first introduction to `StatFs` and was exactly what we needed. On large and complex directories, it was over 1000x faster than recursively getting the file size. Brilliant!

Answer (score 4):

You can query MediaStore for a directory size on internal storage. This is much faster than a recursive method getting the length of each file in a directory. You must have `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission granted.

**Example:**

```
/**
 * Query the media store for a directory size
 *
 * @param context
 *     the application context
 * @param file
 *     the directory on primary storage
 * @return the size of the directory
 */
public static long getFolderSize(Context context, File file) {
  File directory = readlink(file); // resolve symlinks to internal storage
  String path = directory.getAbsolutePath();
  Cursor cursor = null;
  long size = 0;
  try {
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
        new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE},
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " LIKE ?",
        new String[]{path + "/%"},
        null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
        size += cursor.getLong(0);
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
  } finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }
  return size;
}

/**
 * Canonicalize by following all symlinks. Same as "readlink -f file".
 *
 * @param file
 *     a {@link File}
 * @return The absolute canonical file
 */
public static File readlink(File file) {
  File f;
  try {
    f = file.getCanonicalFile();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    return file;
  }
  if (f.getAbsolutePath().equals(file.getAbsolutePath())) {
    return f;
  }
  return readlink(f);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
File DCIM = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
long directorySize = getFolderSize(context, DCIM);
String formattedSize = Formatter.formatFileSize(context, directorySize);
System.out.println(DCIM + " " + formattedSize);
```

**Output:**

> /storage/emulated/0/DCIM 30.86 MB

Comment: yeah, if talking about media files, this is the best solution

Comment: `"/%/%"` - is wrong, it should be `/%` if you don't want to exclude files in root folder -  `getFolderSize(context, folderRoot);`, with your solution `"/%/%"` it would get size only of subfolders in that root folder

Comment: @user924 please don't confuse people without references

Media provider table containing an index of all files in the media storage, including non-media files. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Files

Answer (score 2):

below method return you size of folder:-

```
public static long getFolderSize(File dir) {
long size = 0;
for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        // System.out.println(file.getName() + " " + file.length());
        size += file.length();
    } else
        size += getFolderSize(file);
}
return size;
}
```

call above method :-

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/urfoldername/");

long folder_size=getFolderSize(file);
```

return you size of folder.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

import this

```
import android.text.format.Formatter;
```

For file size

```
public static String fileSize(File file, Context context) {
        return Formatter.formatFileSize(context, file.length());
    }
```

For folder size

```
 public static String forlderSize(File file, Context context) {
        long length = 0;
        File[] folderFiles = file.listFiles();
        for (File f : folderFiles) {
            length += f.length();
        }

        return Formatter.formatFileSize(context, length);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through all files is less than 5 lines of code and the only reasonable way to do this. If you want to get ugly you could also run a system command (Runtime.getRuntime().exec("du");) and catch the output ;)

Comment: Fair enough. Just figured it was such a common use case that there should be some native solution. Laziness is good ... Five lines later, and I'm happy :)

Comment: In Clojure: (defn dir-size [dir] (reduce + (map #(.length %) (.listFiles (new File dir)))))

Comment: I don't think it's safe to rely on du being available and executable.

Comment: How exactly does one fire the "du" command?
I tried - 
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/du -b -d1 "+dir.getCanonicalPath(), new String[]{}, Environment.getRootDirectory());`

didnt work. Nor did -  `(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("du"))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet from Linh Toòng's answer with a couple more checks (mainly to stop Android Studio's warnings!)

```
private long getFolderSize(File file) {

        if (file == null || !file.exists())
            return 0;

        long size = 0;

        if (file.isDirectory()) {

            File[] files = file.listFiles();

            if (files == null || files.length == 0)
                return size;

            for (File f : files)
                size += getFolderSize(f);

        } else
            size += file.length();

        return size;

    }
```