# JackRabbit Webdav :How to know the total space occupied by a folder

Tags: android, jackrabbit

I'm using JackRabbit Webdav Client for Android.I'm unable to get the **size of the specific folder**.Is there any way to find this?For a file **getContentLength** property is returning length.This ***property is not available for folder***.

Thanks in Advance,
Sha

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040912/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-a-folder-on-sd-card-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to collect this information with a `PROPFIND` request for the `D:contentlength` property. Depending on the WebDAV server you're accessing, that should return the sizes of all the files within that folder (with `Depth: 1`) or the entire subtree (with `Depth: infinity`).

You'd still have to iterate through the returned values to calculate the sum of all individual file sizes, but at least you'll only need a single HTTP request for this.

Comment: Thank you.I'll check and let you know

Comment: **Depth:inifinity** is returning a forbidden exception.What does that mean. **Depth:1** and **Depth:0** are working fone.

Comment: Sounds like the WebDAV server you're accessing doesn't allow Depth: infinity requests. Without that feature your client will need to recurse the subtree, calling PROPFIND with Depth: 1 on all subdirectories to collect the sizes of all the files included in the subtree.

Comment: Thanks.I'll iterate the subfolders with depth :1.