# android directory size

Tags: android, file

I need to calculate the physical size of a directory. The naive algorithm to do that could be :

```
public static long getFolderSize(File dir) {
long size = 0;
for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        System.out.println(file.getName() + " " + file.length());
        size += file.length();
    }
    else
        size += getFolderSize(file);
}
return size;
}
```

but how to deal with symbolic links ?

Answer (score 1):

getCanonicalPath() 
This typically involves removing redundant names such as "." and ".." from the pathname, resolving symbolic links (on UNIX platforms).
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the first question – how to calculate physical size:
[How can I get the size of a folder on SD card in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040912/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-a-folder-on-sd-card-in-android/19596456#19596456)

And here is solution how to detect symlinks:
[Java 1.6 - determine symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813710/java-1-6-determine-symbolic-links)

Answer (score -1):

You better use the other API to get the file size the API which is relevant to this would be

```
public static long getFolderSize(File dir) {
long size = 0;
for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        System.out.println(file.getName() + " " + file.getTotalSpace());
        size += file.getTotalSpace();
    }
    else
        size += getFolderSize(file);
}
return size;
}
```

Comment: The doc says for getTotalSpace() : "Returns the total size in bytes of the partition containing this path." -> it doesn't return the file size. + It's only available for api level 9 (i have to run on 1.6)

Comment: + the symbolic links can create circular reference.