# Calculated free size differs from system stats

Tags: android

I am trying to calculate the total amount of file storage used in Android. I used the recursive function used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040912/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-a-folder-on-sd-card-in-android)

When I subtract this size from the total storage of my SD card, I get a number different from what Android gives by using StatFs.

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(path);
long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
long availableBlocks = stat.getFreeBlocks();
return Formatter.formatFileSize(ctx, availableBlocks * blockSize);
```

This is not a difference of a few Kb, but up to 2GB in a 16GB SD card.

I checked a couple of Storage analyzing apps out there in the market and they have the same problem. They say I have 8.3 Gb free while Android keeps telling it's 6Gb (which is the same value I get when connecting the phone to my PC).

What are we missing here?

Comment: Are you rooted, with access to the entire disk? If you have apps installed on SD, your function might not be adding those to your "used" total.

Comment: Actually I'm working with a Galaxy Nexus, which does not have a proper SD card but an emulated one. I guess the same principle applies, though. I will try rooting my device.

Comment: Can't you even get the size of that portion of the SD without rooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in total partition size (not some folder), you can use Java's `File` class also:

```
File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/");

long free = f.getFreeSpace();
long total = f.getTotalSpace();
long usable = f.getUsableSpace();
```

Also, Android probably blocks a portion for sd-apps and data.

Answer (score 1):

> I used the recursive function used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040912/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-a-folder-on-sd-card-in-android)

That function calculates the sizes of the files contained:

> > Just go through all files and sum the length of them:

...but the size of a file does not necessarily equal the amount of space it occupies on disk.

> This is not a difference of a few Kb, but up to 2GB in a 16GB SD card.

This delta should scale with the file count.

Comment: what would be the proper way then?